# How to view green ( VIO odometry) and blue (odometry under GPS global fusion) path in Rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, slam

I'm new in the ROS and I'm trying to run Vins-Fusion with KITTI GPS Fusion (Stereo + GPS), I used this repo https://github.com/HKUST-Aerial-Robotics/VINS-Fusion.
The problem is that I cannot see simultaneously green path and blue path but only one of them. I can switch between their changing from Rviz the fixed frame from map->world and from world->map, but i would like to view both together. [image]

[image]